# Type conversion issue while using descriptor in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, descriptor

I am facing a type conversion issue while using Descriptors in Python. I am not getting why the format is not changed. Please refer below code.

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys
import os

class Celsius():
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return float(self.__celsius)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.__celsius = value
        self.__fahrenheit = float(value * 9/5 + 32)

class Temperature():
    celsius=Celsius()
    def __init__(self,fahrenheit):
        self.fahrenheit=fahrenheit
        self.celsius=(fahrenheit-32)*(5/9)

t1 = Temperature(32)
print(t1.fahrenheit, t1.celsius)
t1.celsius=0
print(t1.fahrenheit, t1.celsius)
```

The output is as below

32 0.0
32 0.0

But, to my understanding, while printing the second line, it should be

32 0.0
32.0 0.0

Can anyone help me understand what is going on in the background and how to achieve expected result?

Comment: you should use a Python tag here so people knowing python can find this and eventually anser your question

Comment: Why are you expecting `fahrenheit` to be different when all you're changing is `celsius`?

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy, thanks for your time to respond. In the __set__ method, fahrenheit is also being modified.

Comment: The `fahrenheit` variable in `Celsius` is not related to the `fahrenheit` variable in `Temperature`.